# How to create a Cosmos DB IQueryable containing only selected properties?

Tags: c#, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I need a method that takes an array of property names `properties` and returns an IQueryable document query `query` with objects containing only these properties. The IQueryable should be reusable for further LINQ-style chaining, e.g. with `.Where(...)`.

**Attempt 1**

```
string sql = $"SELECT {string.Join(",", properties.Select(x => $"c['{x}']"))} FROM c";
IQueryable<MyType> query = DocumentClient.CreateDocumentQuery<MyType>(CollectionUri, sql);
```

This doesn't work because when I attempt to chain a `.Where(x => x.ObjectType == "user")` onto `query`, the following exception is thrown (even when `properties` contain all the properties needed for constructing a `MyType`):

```
System.ArgumentException: 'Expression of type 'System.Linq.IQueryable`1[System.Object]' cannot be used for parameter of type 'System.Linq.IQueryable`1[MyType]' of method 'System.Linq.IQueryable`1[MyType] Where[MyType](System.Linq.IQueryable`1[MyType], System.Linq.Expressions.Expression`1[System.Func`2[MyType,System.Boolean]])''
```

**Attempt 2**

I tried using `dynamic` instead:

```
string sql = $"SELECT {string.Join(",", properties.Select(x => $"c['{x}']"))} FROM c";
IQueryable<dynamic> query = DocumentClient.CreateDocumentQuery(CollectionUri, sql);
```

This doesn't work either: when I attempt to chain a `.Where(x => x["objectType"] == "user")` onto `query`, the code doesn't even compile:

```
CS1963  An expression tree may not contain a dynamic operation
```

**What do do?**

I am using Microsoft.Azure.DocumentDB.Core (2.2.1) on .NET Standard 2.0.

Comment: The SDK doesnt support "LINQ-style chaining" if you stared with `sql`. You need to start with LINQ in order to continue with LINQ

Comment: So I would have to dynamically create an anoymous type based on the given properties and use that to dynamically create a lambda expression tree for the .Select? Isn't there a simpler way?

Comment: With your first attempt, is the Exception thrown when you build, at runtime or doesn’t it compile?

Comment: @Nikolaus At runtime, right at the `.Where(...)` clause.

Comment: Why don't you do the full thing in either SQL or LINQ without missing them up? Mixing them will never work. It's just not supported by the SDK

Comment: @NickChapsas If nothing else works, I will have to use SQL, yes. But I'd like to use LINQ, if possible. But in LINQ it's not trivial to dynamically project onto a given list of properties. Especially since in .NET Standard System.Reflection.Emit is not fully supported, so I can't create an expression tree of a previously unknown anonymous object.

Comment: Then you can't do it with LINQ. Even if you do it would require dynamic expression tree building which would not be fun. I would go with SQL

Comment: Opened a feature request. Maybe it will be done some shiny day: https://github.com/Azure/azure-cosmos-dotnet-v3/issues/4266